# How to "reset" an ember-data model if it's currently dirty

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I can't seem to find the updated api for ember-data that lets you reset a model.

Example, I'm inside my route during the willTransition action and I find the model is dirty. I ask the user if they want to save changes before leaving (ie- they hit the back button on a form by accident / on purpose). If they opt to transition anyway I'd like a way to "reset" the model.

An older api mentioned "removeDirtyFactors" but I'm using 1.0 beta 4+ and this doesn't seem to be around anymore.

```
FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: function() {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      var dirty = this.get('controller.content.isDirty');
      if (dirty && !confirm("ask the user something")) {
        transition.abort();
      }else{
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
model.rollbackAttributes();
```

More details:

[API Documentation](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14.10/classes/DS.Model/methods/rollbackAttributes?anchor=rollbackAttributes)

Comment: Depracated, use rollbackAttributes() instead. http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_rollback